# How many stun attacks can a monk do in one round?

Tags: dnd-3e, monk

A level 15 monk has 4 attacks when using bare-hands.

Is it possible to do 4 stun attacks in one round, or is only 1 stun attack possible and 3 normal attacks?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without taking other feats only one Stunning Fist attempt can be used per round.

According to the 3.5 *Player's Handbook* a creature with the feat Stunning Fist

> may attempt a stunning attack once per day for every four levels [it has] attained..., and **no more than once per round.** (*PH* 101)

Emphasis mine. Being a monk changes this to once per day per monk level but doesn't change the frequency *per round* of Stunning Fist attempts.

The 3.0 *Player's Handbook* reads, "The monk can use this ability [stunning attack] **once per round**, but no more than once per level per day" (*PH* 39). Emphasis mine.

---

The 3.5 feat Rapid Stunning (*CW* 104-5) grants the character the ability to make 1 additional Stunning Fist attempt per round; the feat can be taken multiple times (e.g. a character who takes the Rapid Stunning feat once can make 2 Stunning Fist attempts per round, a character who takes the Rapid Stunning feat twice can make 3 Stunning Fist attempts per round).

Comment: Ok, clear. However, it would be nice if more stun attacks could be done.

Comment: It's dungeons and dragons 3.0